# How to print text (by its class name) in selenium, python?

Tags: python, html, css, selenium

I have this code:

```
try:
    price = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)"))).text
    print(price)
except Exception:
    print("element not found")
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

What I want it to do, is to copy the stock price on yahoo and print it in the terminal. I was thinking, that it might not work because the stock price is changing and so does the class or something, but after trying to copy an unmoving element, it still doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

The code of element on the site looks like that:

```
<span class="Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)" data-reactid="31">41.24</span>
```

Comment: Can you please provide the website you're scraping?

Comment: It's yahoo so I would believe you could share the link to the page ?

Comment: The exact site I was using was 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/NIO?p=NIO&.tsrc=fin-srch'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to locate that element by a wrong locator.
The desired element has a `class` attribute value of `Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)`, it is not an `id` attribute.
So instead of `By.ID,` you should rathe use `By.CSS_SELECTOR`.
Also you should use `visibility_of_element_located` instead of `presence_of_element_located`.
Please try this:

```py
try:
    price = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.Trsdu(0.3s).Fw(b).Fz(36px).Mb(-4px).D(ib)"))).text
    print(price)
except Exception:
    print("element not found")
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Or this:

```py
try:
    price = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span[data-reactid="31"]"))).text
    print(price)
except Exception:
    print("element not found")
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you! I was trying CSS_SELECTOR but had no idea I have to use visibility instead of presence. Why is that?

Comment: There is a process of creation, rendering the elements on the page while it is being loaded. So when the element is initially appearing on the page, existing, it is still not finally completed, will not be clickable and still not including the text it will finally include. So `presence_of_element_located` catches and returns the element while it is existing on the page but maybe not finally ready while `visibility_of_element_located` detects the element on more mature stage when it is visible and in most cases finally completed.